# no matching versions for query "latest" with a local package

Tags: go

```
go version go1.15.2 darwin/amd64
```

within my folder I have two files: `main.go` and `user.go` along with other files such as `go.mod`, `go.sum` etc.

when trying to import the package from `user.go` I get the error in my imports:

> no matching versions for query "latest"

#### user.go

```golang
package user

import (
    "os"
    "os/user"
    "path/filepath"
)
```

#### main.go

```golang
import (
    "fmt"
    "bufio"
    "github.com/ctfrancia/go-dot/user" // <--- error here
    // ...
)
```

I tried following some suggestions such as `go clean -modcache` as [suggested in a git hub issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/27215#issuecomment-416581935)

I'm using gomods so I don't want to disable it. Thanks

Comment: Properly set up your  module which contains all these  packages.

Comment: could you expand?

Answer (score 9):

so my mistake was that the folder in the directory is the package name... well best practice:

so: `goApplication/pkg/hello` all the subsequent `.go` files should have `package hello` at the top

Answer (score 4):

Your files `user.go` and `main.go` are in same directory, in `golang` if you want to work with custom packages you have to create directories with the `same name` as your `package name` in your case your directory structure will be something like:

```
goApplication/rootDir
- main.go
- user
-- user.go
```

Note: You can also use `pkg/user` directory but it is not mandatory for small projects and community has positive as well as negative remarks for this layout structure.